# What is the meaning of this sentence in departed 2006 synopsis?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407887/synopsis).

> Costello notices him and asks him if he's the son of a man Costello
>   knows.

I didn't quite understand this sentence.

Comment: What don't you understand? Costello notices X and asks X if X is the son of Y; Costello knows Y.

Answer (score 1):

> Costello notices him and asks him if he's the son of a man Costello knows.

Let's rewrite this as

> Costello notices the young Colin and asks Colin if Colin is the son of a man (that) Costello knows.

*A man (that) Costello knows* refers to a specific but indefinite man that Costello knows. In other words, Costello has a specific man in mind when he asks this question. But he does not refer to this man by name or some other way of making a definite reference to him. A definite reference usually allows the addressee to identify the referent.

Notice in English we have the indefinite and definite articles, not the specific and nonspecific articles. So the indefinite article can refer to either a specific or nonspecific referent. Another example that shows this is the difference between

> I need to buy a new car.

Here, *a new car* talks about a nonspecific car.

> I bought a new car.

This is a specific reference. The new car could be in the driveway, for example.

Note that this answer looks at the sentence in the synopsis. Whether the synopsis accurately describes the scene is a different issue.